# How to include files in a Visual C++ Windows Forms application

Tags: c++, winforms, include

I have created a new Windows Forms application.

After that, I have added a new form. In my form I have added the `Form_Load` event (by using the form editor).

As far I remember - Visual Studio produced the MainForm.c and MainForm.h files. I had to edit MainForm.c, add main function to it, etc.

I also created a class called `CVEngine`.

**What I want to do**

I want to create an instance of the `CVEngine` class inside my MainForm (see my MainForm.h file, MainForm_Load function at the end of file).

**What is my problem?**

I guess something is wrong with my includes. I don't know much about C++, and this is my first Windows Forms C++ application. I have a little background in C#, PHP, and a bit of Java. I have basic knowledge about C++ and header files, but this MainForm.h generated by Visual Studio is weird (there is code in .h file), and I'm a bit lost.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Sensor Cam, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  CVEngine.cpp
1>  MainForm.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>CVEngine.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall CVEngine::CVEngine(void)" (??0CVEngine@@QAE@XZ) already defined in MainForm.obj
1>CVEngine.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall CVEngine::~CVEngine(void)" (??1CVEngine@@QAE@XZ) already defined in MainForm.obj
1>CVEngine.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall CVEngine::CVEngine(void)" (??0CVEngine@@$$FQAE@XZ) already defined in MainForm.obj
1>CVEngine.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall CVEngine::~CVEngine(void)" (??1CVEngine@@$$FQAE@XZ) already defined in MainForm.obj
1>CVEngine.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100001A) for 'CvCapture'; image may not run
1>MainForm.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000021) for 'CvCapture'; image may not run
1>CVEngine.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00052F) "extern "C" struct CvCapture * __cdecl cvCreateCameraCapture(int)" (?cvCreateCameraCapture@@$$J0YAPAUCvCapture@@H@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CVEngine::CVEngine(void)" (??0CVEngine@@$$FQAE@XZ)
1>MainForm.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000532) "extern "C" struct CvCapture * __cdecl cvCreateCameraCapture(int)" (?cvCreateCameraCapture@@$$J0YAPAUCvCapture@@H@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CVEngine::CVEngine(void)" (??0CVEngine@@$$FQAE@XZ)
1>CVEngine.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00065F) "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@$$FYAHPAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::SparseMat::addref(void)" (?addref@SparseMat@cv@@$$FQAEXXZ)
1>MainForm.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000672) "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@$$FYAHPAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::SparseMat::addref(void)" (?addref@SparseMat@cv@@$$FQAEXXZ)
1>CVEngine.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A00066D) "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::copySize(class cv::Mat const &)" (?copySize@Mat@cv@@$$FQAEXABV12@@Z)
1>MainForm.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000680) "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::copySize(class cv::Mat const &)" (?copySize@Mat@cv@@$$FQAEXABV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::Mat(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@$$FQAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>MainForm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@$$FYAHPAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::SparseMat::addref(void)" (?addref@SparseMat@cv@@$$FQAEXXZ)
1>CVEngine.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@$$FYAHPAHH@Z)
1>MainForm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" struct CvCapture * __cdecl cvCreateCameraCapture(int)" (?cvCreateCameraCapture@@$$J0YAPAUCvCapture@@H@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CVEngine::CVEngine(void)" (??0CVEngine@@$$FQAE@XZ)
1>CVEngine.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" struct CvCapture * __cdecl cvCreateCameraCapture(int)" (?cvCreateCameraCapture@@$$J0YAPAUCvCapture@@H@Z)
1>MainForm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::copySize(class cv::Mat const &)" (?copySize@Mat@cv@@$$FQAEXABV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::Mat(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@$$FQAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>CVEngine.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::copySize(class cv::Mat const &)" (?copySize@Mat@cv@@$$FQAEXABV12@@Z)
1>e:\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Sensor Cam\Debug\Sensor Cam.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**MainForm.h file:**

```
#pragma once

#include "CVEngine.cpp"

namespace SensorCam {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    // using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MainForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
        public:
            MainForm(void)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                //
                // TODO: Add the constructor code here
                //
            }

        protected:
            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            ~MainForm()
            {
                if (components)
                {
                    delete components;
                }
            }

        private:
            System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

            #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
                void InitializeComponent(void)
                {
                    this->SuspendLayout();
                    //
                    // MainForm
                    //
                    this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
                    this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
                    this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(633, 418);
                    this->Name = L"MainForm";
                    this->Text = L"Sensor Cam";
                    this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MainForm::MainForm_Load);
                    this->ResumeLayout(false);
                }
            #pragma endregion

        private: System::Void MainForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
        {
            CVEngine cve = CVEngine::CVEngine();
        }

    };
}
```

**MainForm.cpp file:**

```
#include "MainForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    // Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    SensorCam::MainForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

**CvEngine.cpp file:**

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

class CVEngine
{
    public:
        CVEngine();
        ~CVEngine();

    private:
        CvCapture* capture;
};

CVEngine::CVEngine()
{
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
    if (!capture)
    {
        // Todo: error handling
    }
}

CVEngine::~CVEngine()
{

}
```

Comment: You are including your .cpp file leading to multiple definitions of functions.

Comment: This is what linker said ;) How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it compiling, create a **cv_engine.h** file

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

class CVEngine
{
public:
    CVEngine();
    ~CVEngine();

private:
    CvCapture* capture;

};
```

**cv_engine.cpp**

```
#include "cv_engine.h"

CVEngine::CVEngine()
{
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
    if (!capture)
    {
        // todo: error handling
    }
}

CVEngine::~CVEngine()
{

}
```

Then `#include "cv_engine.h"` in Mainform.h

Also, you shouldn't really do things like this in header files...

`using namespace cv;`

When you can just use scope...

`cv::CvCapture* capture;`

Comment: I still have errors, linker cannot see cvCapture. But I clicked "solved" because now includes are correct, and new problem is not related. I think  CLR is not compatybile with openCV... :(

Comment: I think you are using the wrong class. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/highgui.html

C++ should use VideoCapture by the looks of it.

Comment: Still no success: `unresolved token (0A0005DD) "public: __cdecl cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)`